# String Manipulation W3Resources

Tags: mysql

The question asks to discard the last 3 characters from the column. The functions RIGHT() AND SUBSTRING() come to mind but they return the extracted characters and not the original, correct?

- If so, would a CASE statement come into play?

https://www.w3resource.com/mysql-exercises/string-exercises/write-a-query-to-get-the-employee-id-email-id.php

Comment: The solution `REVERSE(SUBSTR(REVERSE(email), 4))` was already given in your link above.

Comment: You want SUBSTRING() with LENGTH().   SELECT SUBSTRING(MyField, 0, (LENGTH(MyField)-3)) AS ExtractString;

Comment: Yes, I over thought this question. I forgot that SUBSTR is able to discard characters, I thought it only returns the characters that you specify such as the functions RIGHT and LEFT. Thank you.